# How to change the color of the text of 'active' class in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to change the color of the text in **`active`** class in the bootstrap framework.

```
.active{
 color:#720B87;
}
```

but it is taking the default one.

Comment: You can override the default style, with yours.

Comment: have you changed in bootstrap framework css file

Comment: that's because Bootstrap's selector probably has more specificity than yours, use your browser's inspection tools to check which rule is being applied to the element and use that selector

Comment: I tried what you said @user1671639 but It didn't help

Comment: I didn't change the main bootstrap.css but created a new one and added it after bootstrap.css @rakesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about a navbar `.active` link, and are using the latest Bootstrap 3, it would be..

```
.navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color:#720B87;
}
```

For 2.x (if you're not using `.navbar-inverse`)..

```
.navbar .nav>li>a {
  color:#720B87;
}
```

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2. So can you suggest for that. Anyway thank you @skelly for your answer :)

Comment: you'll have to use !important if you are planning on toggling .active class, keep that in mind.

Comment: Sthanks Skelly! :-) That did it. Also I agree with DirkDigler, I had to use !important on my background-color and color elements to help override the default bootstrap active values.